# Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s) - Error in binary search methods

Tags: java, eclipse, recursion, compiler-errors, binary-search

Here is my code. I can't find the problem. Please help me. I have this error in Eclipse:

> Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)

There error is written right next to the line in the recursive method that says

```
if (arr[mid] == item) {
```

But it seems to me like all my braces and constructors and everything are fine. I also have an error on the constructor which says:

> Missing method return type.

I don't think the constructor should have a return type, right?

```
public final class IntegerBinSearch {
    /** 
     * Default constructor.
     */
    private IntegerBinarySearch() {

    }
    /**
     * Returns the index of the item that you are looking for, -1 
     * if the item isn't in the array.
     * The array must be sorted.
     * 
     * @param array the array that will be searched.
     * @param item the item that the method will try to find.
     * @return the index of the item's location, returns -1 if not found.
     */
    public static int binarySearch(Integer[] array, int item) {
        int high = array.length - 1;
        int low = 0;
        int mid = (high + low) / 2;
        for (int i = array.length; i > 0; i /= 2) {
            if (array[mid] == item) {
                return mid;
            } else if (array[mid] > item) {
                high = mid - 1;
                mid = (high + low) / 2;
            } else {
                low = mid + 1;
                mid = (high + low) / 2;
            }
        }
        return -1;

    }
    /**
     *  Returns the index of the location of the given item, else returns -1.
     *  
     * @param array array of Integers that will be searched.
     * @param item item that will be searched for.
     * @param low lower bound of the array's contents to search.
     * @param high upper bound of the array's contents to search.
     * @return returns the index of the location of the given item, returns -1 if item is not found.
     */
    public static int binarySearchRecursive(Integer[] arr, int item, int low, int high) {
        int mid = (high + low) / 2;
        if (arr[mid] == item) {
          return mid;  
        }
         else(arr[mid] > item) {
            return binarySearchRecursive(arr, item, low, mid - 1);
        } else {
            return binarySearchRecursive(arr, item, mid + 1, high);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The constructor error is because your class is named **IntegerBinSearch**, but your constructor is named **IntegerBinarySearch** (ah, typos!). Also, `else (array[mid] > item)`'s error is because you're missing the word `if`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write else if statement whenever you use multiple conditions

as you should replace

```
else (arr[mid] > item) {
```

with

```
else if (arr[mid] > item) {
```

And constructor name must be same as class name as @Adam said

Please try